# How do I call into correct store 'collection' with ngrx-store?

Tags: angular, rxjs, dom-events, ngrx, reducers

I have two collections of data (sample app - trying to learn ngrx) of counter and urls. I can correctly pull and display each of the 2 stores in their respective components. Using the counter example from ngrx-store, I can also increment & decrement the counter. I added a reducer for urls which right now just has a default in the action switch.

PROBLEM: When I increment the counter, the url default action is also fired. I'm not correctly selecting only 1 action on 1 reducer. How do I do that?

POSSIBLE ANSWER?: I think each reducer's actions need to be distinct? Ie, 'counter-increment' and 'url-increment' versus both reducers using 'increment'? Or is there another method?

I'm new to ngrx and rxjs so the simplest/most direct code would be helpful.

```
// app.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import '@ngrx/core';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import { AppComponent  }  from './components/app.component';
import { UrlListComponent, UrlItemComponent, ListComponent, ListItemComponent, CounterComponent } from './components/index'
import {  counterReducer, urlReducer} from './reducers/index';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule, 
    HttpModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore({counter: counterReducer, urls: urlReducer}) 
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UrlItemComponent, UrlListComponent, ListComponent, ListItemComponent, CounterComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){console.log("AppModule");}
}

// app.component.ts
import { Injectable, Component, Output, Input, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule  } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT, RESET, Url } from '../reducers/index';
import { ListComponent, UrlListComponent, CounterComponent} from './index'

export interface AppState {
  counter: number;
  urls : Url[]
}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id, //system js variable name for relative path
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <counter-comp [counter]="counter" ></counter-comp>
        <url-list [urls]="urls"></url-list>
        <list [innerArray]="myarray"></list>
    `,
    providers: [],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
    counter: number;
    urls: Url[];
    myarray: number[] = [];

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
        console.log('AppComponent constructor');

        this.store.select(state => state.counter)
            .subscribe(data => this.counter = data);
        this.store.select(state => state.urls)
          .subscribe(data => this.onUrlsEmitted(data));

        this.myarray.push(1);
        this.myarray.push(2);
        this.myarray.push(3);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
            console.log('AppComponent ngOnInit');
    }
    // executed once user data arrives from the store
    public onUrlsEmitted(data:Url[]){
        console.log('AppComponent onUrlsEmitted');
        this.urls = data;
        if(!data || !data.length){ 
            console.log("no url data arrived");
        }
    }
}

// counter.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Url, AppState, INCREMENT, DECREMENT, RESET } from '../reducers/index';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter-comp',
  template: `
        <div class='counter'>
        <div>Current Count: {{ counter }}</div>
        <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>       
        <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
        <button (click)="reset()">Reset Counter</button>
        </div>
  `
  ,
    styles:[`
        div { width: 100%; }
        .counter { background-color: #99bbff; }
    `]
})
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input() counter: number;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
    }

    increment(){
        console.log("counter.component.ts increment");
        this.store.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT });
    }

    decrement(){
        console.log("counter.component.ts decrement");
        this.store.dispatch({ type: DECREMENT });
    }

    reset(){
        console.log("counter.component.ts reset");
        this.store.dispatch({ type: RESET });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('CounterComponent input: ' + this.counter);
    }
}

// counter.ts
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
export const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';
export const RESET = 'RESET';

export const counterReducer: ActionReducer<number> = (state: number = 0, action: Action) => {
    console.log("counterReducer action.type " + action.type);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
    switch (action.type) {
        case INCREMENT:
            return state + 1;

        case DECREMENT:
            return state - 1;

        case RESET:
            return 0;

        default:
            console.log("counterReducer default");
            return state;
    }
}
// url.ts
import { ActionReducer, Action } from '@ngrx/store';
//export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
//export const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';
//export const RESET = 'RESET';

export interface Url{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

let initialState = function(){
    return [{id:1, name:"Dina"},{id:2, name:"Wayne"},{id:3,name:"kids"}];
}

export const urlReducer: ActionReducer<Url[]> = (state: Url[] = initialState(), action: Action) => {
     console.log("urlReducer action.type " + action.type);
     console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
     switch (action.type) {
        default:
            console.log("urlReducer default");
            console.log(state);
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: github is https://github.com/dfberry/ng2-quickstart/tree/rxjs-store and docker is updated to pull the ngrx branch

Comment: Can you stript this example to necessary minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `distinctUntilChanged` operator.

`this.store.select(state => state.urls).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(data => this.onUrlsEmitted(data))`

Comment: I tried distinctUntilChanged. The code still runs the urlReducer when I only mean to increment counter via counterReducer. Perhaps there is some setup I'm missing to get the 2 'tables' to separate on eventing.

Comment: Yes. When you dispatch an action it's should fire all the reducers. that's why we use select on the type of an action.

Comment: see more: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#actions

Comment: Doesn't store.select internally call distinctUntilChanged? References: https://netbasal.com/lets-talk-about-select-and-reselect-in-ngrx-store-177a2f6045a8 https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples/blob/master/counter/src/app/components/counter.ts https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510